# Nuxt 2 Bridge Composition API: how to access context (such as `$auth`)?

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth, nuxt-bridge

With Nuxt 2 I could do

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default class Login extends Vue {
  mounted() {
    if (!this.$auth.loggedIn) {
      this.$auth.login()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How do I change this to Nuxt 2 Bridge Composition API?

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
onMounted(() => {
  // ?
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`useNuxtApp()`](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/going-further/nuxt-app/) gives access to the context:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
onMounted(() => {
  const { $auth } = useNuxtApp()
})
</script>
```

However, at the moment typing with Nuxt 2 Bridge only works on the `nuxt2Context` property:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
onMounted(() => {
  const { nuxt2Context } = useNuxtApp()

  if (!nuxt2Context.$auth.loggedIn) {
    nuxt2Context.$auth.login()
  }
})
</script>
```